# Renaming a PHP file enables jquery form validation?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, ajaxform

This is a very odd problem. I have a signup form, signup.php, which uses the jQuery validate plugin to validate it.

Twice in last 2 months, the form serialization abruptly failed (see code below) and no `input` values get submitted regardless of what I put in them. The weird part is if I simply rename the signup.php file (e.g., to signup0.php) then the form serialization works again and the form validates. My signup.php file is included in my main template.php file using the following code:

PHP

```
<? include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/views/forms/signup.php';?>
```

JS:

```
beforeSubmit:function(formData, $form, options)
  var thisFormData = $.param(data.formData); 
  console.log('live data: ' + thisFormData); 
  //this yields no data regardless of what I enter in any of the input fields
  //subsequently $($form).validate() fails
```

Does anyone have any clue what is going on here? I also have a login.php form included in this template.php file which never suffers this problem. This has to be a PHP rather than a JS problem since renaming the PHP file can correct it, right? The only thing I can think is that multiple hidden instances of signup.php are being created somehow but that seems like the thoughts of a crazy person.

Comment: really odd, its did you checked in two different browsers? try also clean temp files & cookies

Comment: yeah same problem in chrome and firefox, how do i clean up temp files?

Comment: @timpeterson, just clear your browser history (completely). Are you using some sort of APC that might also cache variables?

Comment: -@daniel5, I'm using memcache, but why the difference between login.php vs. signup.php?

Comment: @timpeterson this sounds like overzealous caching. Check your web server settings

Comment: @TashPemhiwa thanks, i'm using Nginx, know what i should be looking for? Something in my PHP build?

Comment: @timpeterson I am not familiar with nginx, but I think you will need to check anything related to caching in your nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome settings -> clear data..
but if its reproduce on other browser, i dont believe it will helps you..

Comment: If you don't believe it helps, then do not post it as an answer.